# C# - Opening text file with notepad minimized?

Tags: c#, process, minimize, notepad

It doesn't look like the Minimized style has an effect:

```
string logFilePath = @"c:\mylog.log";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(logFilePath) {WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `UseShellExecute = true`?

Comment: well I have windows vista, it worked wit the code you posted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Community Comments section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx#CommunityContent) of the MSDN page for the [WindowStyle Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) says:

> **To use Hidden, you'll need UseShellExecute = true**
>
> To use Hidden, you'll need UseShellExecute = true among other things.  These requirements should be noted in the documentation, but aren't.

Have you tried that? Maybe it applies to Minimized  as well.